# cryptsetup: ERROR:sda5_crypt: maximum number of tries exceeded

Tags: 18.10

New to Ubuntu. Encrypted disk, getting this error message:
"cryptsetup: ERROR:sda5_crypt: maximum number of tries exceeded"

Now what do I do?

Answer (score 2):

Well, you have to figure out the right password or reinstall...

I hit a similar problem with my first encrypted installs a long time ago:

- when I entered the key phrase for the disk during install the keyboard was actually still using a default QWERTY layout,
- but when I enter the key phrase during boot, the keyboard uses my expected AZERTY layout.

So while I thought I entered ZERO (keys 2,3,4,9 on the top row of AZERTY)(*) the system got WERO (keys (keys 2,3,4,9 on the top row of QWERTY). So in AZERTY mode I have to enter WERO to unlock.

Since then, when I install, I pick a layout-agnostic key phrase (such as TYPO), and later change the key to something possibly AZERTY-sensitive but more secure.

Of course if you have a QWERTY keyboard the matter is different... but an overlooked CapsLock or NumLock could put you in a similar situation.

(*) passwords have been changed to protect the innocent.

Comment: Thanks. I'll check for possible keyboard/capslock/numlock issues.

Answer (score 0):

Hello Stan :) If keyboard/capslock/numlock issues failed. Here are the steps for an additional possible resolution.

**Steps**

1. This message is display: `maximum number of tries exceeded`
2. Wait at least 60 seconds
3. Double-check your device present keyboard/capslock/numlock configuration. Try again your password.

---

Below is the same answer as above. But with details if you're interested in those.

**Note**

At step 2 above, during those 60 seconds, any entered passwords are ignored. Including correct ones. It's called a "sleep" period.

**Contribute**

For those not happy with this present cryptsetup "sleep" challenge, suggestion or patch are welcome at this official cryptsetup repository at  https://gitlab.com/cryptsetup/cryptsetup

**Attribution**

For interested software engineers, this code show details about the "sleep" at https://lists.debian.org/debian-user/2017/12/msg00523.html